# iOS 7 beta and SDL build fail

Tags: ios, sdl, ios7

I am not unable to build and run the demo projects for iOS which are included in the SDL download. I am getting the error below and don't know how to resolve this issue. On my simulator, the project is compiling but the sample projects are not running on my iPhone. I am using iOS 7 beta 3 on both of them (simulator & iphone).

The following build error occurs:

```
 ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In addition, the sample program includes a main function, so shouldn't it work normally?

Comment: iOS7 is still under NDA - ask this on the Apple forums, not here.